# Скрипт мониторинга fps на android

Tags: android, python, android-studio, производительность, adb

Можно ли на питоне или в консоли с помощью adb написать скрипт/команду, который будет мониторить fps на девайсе во время игры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Набросал скрипт на *Python*, который будет выводить **fps**. Есть ограничения - точность результатов и наличие `root` прав на телефоне.

```
import time
import re
import logging
import datetime
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def getSurfaceStatsLegacy():
    results, err = Popen('adb shell "su -c \'service call SurfaceFlinger 1013\'"', shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()
    match = re.search('^Result: Parcel\((\w+)', results)
    cur_surface = 0
    if match:
      try:
        cur_surface = int(match.group(1), 16)
      except Exception:
        logging.error('Failed to parse current surface from ' + match.group(1))
    else:
      logging.warning('Failed to call SurfaceFlinger surface ' + results)
    return {
        'page_flip_count': cur_surface,
        'timestamp': datetime.datetime.now(),
    }

def main():
    before = getSurfaceStatsLegacy()
    while True:
        after = getSurfaceStatsLegacy()
        td = after['timestamp'] - before['timestamp']
        seconds = td.seconds + td.microseconds / 1e6
        frame_count = (after['page_flip_count'] -
                         before['page_flip_count'])
        print("%d %s" %( int(round(frame_count / seconds)), "fps"))
        before = after
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, будет интересно разобрать. Вопрос ещё, рут права нужны в любом случае или можно обойти это в коде?

Comment: @Art этот скрипт запускается на хосте, телефон подключен к PC по USB. рут права нужны в любом случае, иначе выполнение команды `service call SurfaceFlinger 1013` вернет Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Комманда `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --latency` в первой строке вывода показывает системный FPS в наносекундах (т.е. для получения значения в герцах надо поделить 1000000000 на число наносекунд). `root` не требуется.

Comment: только сейчас дошли руки потестить) Попробовал ваш вариант, но вывод всегда даёт одно число и в переводе с наносекунд - 59 фпс

Comment: если реальный FPS выше, то после VSYNC как раз 60FPS и должно получаться. вы под достаточной нагрузкой пробовали? когда FPS заведомо ниже 60?

Comment: Конечно, выходил / заходил в игры, переключался между уровнями и т.п. , стоит 59 без изменений